# Multiple pictures in tabularx environment - inside a multicolumn

Tags: graphics, multicolumn

I have a Problem and i cant get it to work ...
I want to place multiple Pictures underneath each other in a multicolumn.
Linebreaking doesn't seem to work in multicolumn. is there another way to linebreak in multicolumn?

Here is a minimal example not with two figures but with text. the text is placed right next to the figure and not underneath it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx} 



\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lr}
test & test \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{test.jpg} \newline test \newline test}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the specifier of the `\multicolumn` to `p{\textwidth}`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lr}
    test & test \\[1ex]
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering}p{\textwidth}}{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{example-image-16x10.pdf} \\[2ex]
    \fcolorbox{Tomato}{PeachPuff}{\color{PeachPuff}\rule{0.6\textwidth}{1cm}}\\[1ex] test}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works when you place each of the figures in its own `multicolumn` and then linebreak outside of the `multicolumn` environment. Same for text:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lr}
test & test \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{test.jpg} }\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{test.jpg} }\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{test test}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{test test}\\
test & test\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know that i could use multiple \multicolumn commands but in my case this doesnt work (i have a function that calls a for-Loop which checks if Pictures are available and if so they should be placed underneath each other).